# Get Button and Textfield data , when they are added programmatically in swift 5

Tags: swift, dynamic, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a dynamic form where I'm creating textfields and Buttons based on json response. the count of buttons and textfields may vary.
When I tap on button to show a actionsheet with a list of options(corresponding data of each button) or put data in textfield how I can get data of that specific fields saved in their specific variables?

```
 //Buttons
 func subViewButton(placeholder:String){
 let myFirstButton = UIButton()
            myFirstButton.setTitle(placeholder, for: .normal)
            myFirstButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
            myFirstButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray
            myFirstButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 40)
            myFirstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
            formStackView.addArrangedSubview(myFirstButton)
            formStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
 }
 @objc func pressed() {
    //action here for specific button press
}
 //Textfields
 func subviewTextField(placeholder:String){
    let tectfield = SkyFloatingLabelTextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 40))
    tectfield.placeholder = placeholder
    tectfield.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    tectfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    tectfield.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing
    tectfield.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    tectfield.delegate = self
    tectfield.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tectfield.selectedTitleColor = Utility.GlobalVariable.yellowColor
    tectfield.selectedLineColor = Utility.GlobalVariable.yellowColor
    tectfield.tintColor = Utility.GlobalVariable.blueColor
    formStackView.spacing = 8
    formStackView.addArrangedSubview(tectfield)
    formStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
}
```

I have a for loop where I'm populating the form based on a key where its a define that it is button or textfield.

Answer (score 0):

As you create all your button with a for loop, you could enumerate them so that you get the index of data field and assign the index as a tag to each button.

Once you'll be tapping on the button it will trigger the IBAction which provide the button itself as an argument (sender). You can then now spot which button has been tapped from its tag, and use the latter to retrieve the associated data.

```swift
private let formFields = ["Name", "Age", "Gender"]

private func createButtonsFromDataArray() {
    for (index, formField) in formFields.enumerated() {
        let button = UIButton()
        // [...]
        button.tag = index
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        // [...]
    }

}

@objc func pressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("The associated data to the button is \(formFields[sender.tag])")
}
```

Regarding the textfield you can do the same except that you keep a reference to all the textfields that you create into an array. By proceeding that way, you'll be able to retrieve the `textField.text` information of each textfield and then create a `Encodable` struct, to which you provide the different information you want to post through your upload / POST URLRequest.

```swift
private var formTextFields: [UITextField] = []

private func createTextFieldFromDataArray() {
    for (index, formField) in formFields.enumerated() {
        let textField = UITextField()
        // [...]
        textField.tag = index // probably not necessary as the position in the array would provide the index but... depends on which solution you want to go with
        formTextFields.append(textField)
        // [...]
    }

}

private func postFormData() {
    // here obviously you have multiple options
    // But let's say the form fields are not dynamic you can create a struct, if not you would have to encode to `[String:Any]` and reinterpret that on the backend.

    var dataToUpload: [String: Any] = []
    for (index, formField) in formFields.enumerated() {
        dataToUpload[formField] = formTextFields[index].text
    }


    let encoder = JSONEncoder()
    let data = encoder.encode(dataToUpload)

    // URLSession.shared. etc.

}
```

and the struct if not dynamics:

```swift
struct FormData: Encodable {
    let age: Int
    let name: String
    let gender: String
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I have another query. How do I post these values in a post request? Do I have to save them in different variables?

Comment: @Bilal I did edit the post so that you have a small idea, but the scope of the question is starting to get too wide. so please make my post the answer, then ask another question with a reduced scope to fit the policy. A pleasure to help, you're welcome :)